# SSRS Standalone install license

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, license

For performance reasons we are thinking about moving our SSRS installation to a separate server.
Since you can have a standalone installation of SSRS.

Question being, if we install SSRS (standalone) on a new server with X cores.
Do we need a separate enterprise license for this server?

Is there a licensing cost for installing standalone SSRS?

Or is the license used from the instance where the ReportServerDB is located ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licensing questions are off topic at DBA.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to buy a separate license for the server running SSRS. Unless you have a virtual host where you have bought an enterprise license for every core in the server (see the chapter on [Licensing for Maximum Virtualization](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/6/9C6EB70A-8D52-48F4-9F04-08970411B7A3/SQL_Server_2016_Licensing_Guide_EN_US.pdf))